# Cannot stop my robot's movement from going back on itself

Tags: java

I have a fairly standard ascii maze with a bot that moves around the board picking up the required amount of gold before finding an exit and leaving (winning!). I cannot, however, seem to stop the robot from going back on itself, hence the time taken to win takes too long.

E.g. if the bot has just moved south then I would not want it to be able to move north immediately after that.

I know it could be more efficient but don't tell me how to improve the bot, just how to stop the movement going back on itself.

The `response.equals("FAIL")` refers to if the move would take the bot into a wall(symbolised with a `#`).

```
public static void randomMove(){
    String reponse = "FAIL";
    int lastrand = -1;
    int rand = -1;
    while(reponse.equals("FAIL")){      
        lastrand = rand;
        rand = new Random().nextInt(4);
        if(rand==0 && lastrand != 1){
            reponse = robot.Move("N",'B');
        }else if(rand==1 && lastrand != 0){
            reponse = robot.Move("S",'B');
        }else if(rand==2 && lastrand != 3){ 
            reponse = robot.Move("E",'B');
        }else if(rand==3 && lastrand != 2){ 
            reponse = robot.Move("W",'B');
        }else{
            continue;
        }
        lastrand = rand;
    }

    if(robot.getNewSquare()=='G'){
        robot.print(robot.Pickup());
    }
    if(reponse == "Winner!"){
        robot.print(reponse);
        robot.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give `Robot` an instance variable `lastMove`. Every time you call `Move` check to see if the direction passed in is the same as `lastMove`; if they are equal return "FAIL" so that the loop continues; if not return whatever you're returning on success.

Comment: Something to keep in mind; what if the robot ran into a dead end? It would _have_ to retreat, yes?

Comment: I'm also confused by your comparisons.  Why are you checking if rand is 0 and lastrand is not 1?  Why not just first check if(rand != lastrand)?

Comment: @jgitter because you should be able to move left twice in a row, just not left after a right

Comment: Have some trigger points on the level. Mark them with some special symbol which isn't printed, but is used to calculate the above logic. Only call randomMove when the robot is present on the trigger point. These should be points from where the robot can move in possibly more than two directions and places where there is no direction to go but backwards (dead end).

Comment: Your code would be a lot more clear if you used an enum for directions instead of "magic" integer codes.

Comment: @ChrisForrence at the moment I have not been given any maps with dead ends so I won't worry about that just yet.

Comment: could be an extension later on though with @Awfully Awesome 's idea.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you added the `else continue` with the thought of "don't update lastrand if we didn't move". But then you still have a `lastrand = rand;` at the start of the loop, which updates it anyway. So if you randomly get North twice in a row, it will go that way.

Comment: even removing `lastrand = rand;` doesn't make it work. i have tried almost every variation of the code and i just can't seem to get it work.